# cannot dynamically add views android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view, layout-inflater

I'm trying to implement a custom view with textview children added dynamically. But it isn't showing any result. there are no error, just nothing shows up:

My Class:

```
public class CustomPasscodeEntryView extends LinearLayout {

private Context mContext;
private CustomPasscodeEntryView thisView;

public CustomPasscodeEntryView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    /* same as below */
}

public CustomPasscodeEntryView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    /*same as below*/
}

public CustomPasscodeEntryView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mContext = context;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    thisView = (CustomPasscodeEntryView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_passcode_entry,this);

}

public void addDigit(int digit){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final pinView pin = (pinView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.password_bullet_view,null);
    pin.setDigit(digit);
    thisView.addView(pin, thisView.getChildCount());
    pin.setVisibility(VISIBLE);


}
public void deleteDigit(){
    if(getChildCount() > 0)
        thisView.removeView(thisView.getChildAt(getChildCount()-1));
}


}

class pinView extends TextView {

int digit;

public pinView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public pinView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public pinView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setText('•');
}

public void setDigit(int digit) {
    this.digit = digit;
    this.setText(Integer.toString(digit));
}
}
```

and my XMLs:
view_passcode_entry:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
</LinearLayout>
```

password_bullet_view:

```
  <com.github.lockpin.lollipin.lib.views.pinView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:text="•"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="2.5dp"
/>
```

EDIT: the view in my activity:

```
    <com.github.lockpin.lollipin.lib.views.CustomPasscodeEntryView
        android:id="@+id/custom_passcode_entry_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/pin_code_text_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
```

I cant see what's wrong, and I've followed tutorials online and made a few changes. Am I missing something here? Or is this plainly wrong?

Comment: what do you want to do in you custom password view? animate what?

Comment: i want to animate the entry of each new digit (fade in) and when a new letter is typed, the old one converts into a bullet. (Like in the Pixel / Nexus lockscreen)

Comment: ok so use a custom `android.text.method.TransformationMethod`

Comment: I did use that at first. It doesnt animate though, and works directly with `Charsequences` and `Strings` that are passed onto the `TextView` (or atleast thats what i inferred from it). I'm not familiar with `Spannables` and so decided to do this instead (and it works! :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong view id `view_passcode_entry` when inflating view, which is instance of `LinearLayout`, and typecast it to `CustomPasscodeEntryView`.

You only need to use `this` when call `addView()` in `addDigit()` because `CustomPasscodeEntryView` is also  instance of `LinearLayout`. So layout `view_passcode_entry` can be removed because it is not needed anymore.

```
this.addView(pin, this.getChildCount());
```

But if you want to add view `view_passcode_entry` as child of `CustomPasscodeEntryView` instance then you need to add `thisView` also

```
private ViewGroup thisView;
...
thisView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_passcode_entry, this);
this.addView(thisView, 0);
```

and then if you want to use `view_passcode_entry` as parent of `pinView` then you can use

```
 thisView.addView(pin, thisView.getChildCount());
```

Comment: No, thats not it. I added it there. Sorry i didnt mention that.

Comment: Funnily enough, I started out using `this` but the app crashed without an error so i switched to thisView(which, looking at it now, was STUPID). now i switched back to `this` and it works. Apparently the crash was due to some other part of my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it because of you have already mentioned the height of CustomPasscodeEntryView in the xml (android:layout_height="40dp")?

Can you try wrap_content instead?

Comment: i tried wrap_content at first. it didn't work. I wanted to check whether the view was visible using the `show layout bounds` in `developer options` so I changed it. The layout is there. the children aren't being added